# How to permanently hide files after adding into gitignore file

Tags: ios, git, github, frameworks, gitlab

I've multiples Pods, our own SDK which generated Framework and Bundles which is eventually use in App, every time I changed into my SDK those Bundle and Framework gets changed, and all Frameworks and bundle files comes into unstaging files in my project hierarchy which I don't want because these are unnecessary files and added into staging with my important file which I changed and want to commit, same is the case with Pods. As shown in screenshot. 
[image]

My project is hosted on Gitlab. What I already attempted. 
Added all unnecessary files into gitignore and commit push gitignore file.
Every time I use to discard them or remove them but regenerate after update my framework and bundle.

Let me know to fix this issue.
Looking for suggestion and answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is that exact location?  It looks to be within the app bundle of the app you are building?

Comment: I placed on my App but not in App bundle.

Comment: It's not clear from looking at the screenshot where in your repo those files are.

Comment: These all are in my app where bundle and sdk and pods are located.

Comment: @Aleem if these files were tracked at some point, you have to apply an extra step to tell git to "forget" these files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057 which I suggested as duplicate.

Comment: I solved my problem by using this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/671060